# Can we use KAA 0.8.0 Client SDK with KAA 0.8.1 Server?

Tags: iot, kaa

Can we use KAA 0.8.0 Client SDK with KAA 0.8.1 Server?

Is it possible to use KAA 0.8.0 Client SDK with KAA 0.8.1 Server? 
We are planning to upgrade our server, will this affect our current endpoints?
Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kaa 0.8.0 clients are compatible with the 0.8.1 server.